# what's wrong with git clone? index-pack died of signal 99 error

Tags: git, version-control, git-clone

this issue is different from [Git push "error: index-pack died of signal 9"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985124/git-push-error-index-pack-died-of-signal-9)

the error message is as follows:

```
remote: Counting objects: 40512, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8896/8896), done.
remote: Total 40512 (delta 31079), reused 40394 (delta 30980)
Receiving objects: 100% (40512/40512), 6.05 MiB | 22 KiB/s, done.
error: index-pack died of signal 99)   
fatal: index-pack failed

real    1292050m43.682s
user    0m23.645s
sys     0m5.872s
```

one more case:

```
remote: Counting objects: 18389, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4951/4951), done.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly MiB | 22 KiB/s      
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

real    7m18.359s
user    0m4.448s
sys     0m1.860s
```

Comment: What OS are you using? What git version are you using? What protocol are you using when cloning? (ssh, git, https, ?)

Comment: If you do it again do you get exactly the same error?  I'm thinking it might be a network issue perhaps?  How quickyl does it take for the error to come up?

Comment: What is the host (ISP) you are pushing to?  Presumably not dreamhost.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant yes, i get the same error. why DH, is there anything special with DH? btw, i am using github..

Answer (score 7):

This is a loss of network connectivity more than likely - error 99 is coming from your ssh

```
Connection Closed By Remote Host
```

Try with

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git clone REPO new_dir
```

That will let you know exactly where it is timing out.