# Terminal error shows "error: fetch died of signal 9" when trying to do a git pull on terminal"

Tags: terminal, github-pages, apple-m1

I am trying to do a `git pull` from a github repo on terminal using a new mac M1 chip silicon.

And I get this error:

```
"error: fetch died of signal 9"
```

So far I can't find anything online about this error.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Signal 9 is `SIGKILL`, which normally means something did a `kill -9` on the process. I don't know what could be causing this in your situation, though.

Comment: But maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7985124/3216427