# git push fails with a memory error in a large repo when using GitHub checkout actions in a Kubernetes pod

Tags: git, docker, kubernetes, memory, action

We have a [Public API](https://github.com/ACMILabs/acmi-api) that includes a nightly [metadata updater](https://github.com/ACMILabs/acmi-api/blob/main/scripts/update-api.sh) run via Cron in a pod deployed with [Github Actions](https://github.com/ACMILabs/acmi-api/blob/main/.github/workflows/main.yml) and [Kubernetes](https://github.com/ACMILabs/acmi-api/blob/main/kubernetes/api.yml). Overnight the updater pulls fresh metadata from our private API, and then commits those changes and pushes them to itself to refresh both the Github repo and trigger a lint/test/build/deployment.

We're using [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) which fetches a single commit by default.

After a few weeks of updating our ~43,000 record ~700mb repo we started seeing failures at the `git push` step: `error: pack-objects died of signal 9`

```sh
Enumerating objects: 11754, done.
Counting objects: 100% (10881/10881), done.
error: pack-objects died of signal 9
error: pack-objects died of signal 9
error: remote unpack failed: eof before pack header was fully read
```

[Increasing pod resources](https://github.com/ACMILabs/acmi-api/pull/60/files) didn't help.

Comment: Tonight we're going to try doing a `git fetch --unshallow` to see if that allows the `git push` command to compare changes with less memory use. See PR: https://github.com/ACMILabs/acmi-api/pull/63/files

And also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36189893

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using `git fetch --unshallow` the pod was able to [complete](https://github.com/ACMILabs/acmi-api/commit/cfb4e37fddc830b90ff15c0f4baafd2b43774b13) a `git commit` and `git push` to re-deploy itself.